# c# Generic class for handling static method

Tags: c#, generics, static-methods

I want to have a base generic class to handle model conversion.
Below are the model interfaces

```cs
    public interface IRawModel
    {
    }

    public interface IDtoModel
    {
    }

    public interface IRawDto<T1, T2>
        where T1 : IRawModel
        where T2 : IDtoModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get DTO model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">Raw item</param>
        /// <returns>DTO item</returns>
        static T2 GetDto(T1 item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Model classes

```cs
    public class UserDto : IDtoModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets firstname.
        /// </summary>
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets lastname.
        /// </summary>
        public string? LastName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets email.
        /// </summary>
        public string? Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class User : IRawModel, IRawDto<User, UserDto>
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets first name.
        /// </summary>
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets last name.
        /// </summary>
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets email.
        /// </summary>
        public string Email { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets DTO model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user">User</param>
        /// <returns>User DTO</returns>
        public static UserDto GetDto(User user) => new UserDto
        {
            
            Email = user.Email,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            
        };
    }
```

When i get a collection of users and to handle conversion in generic way i created below base class

```cs
    public class BaseRepository<T1, T2, T3>
        where T1 : IRawModel
        where T2 : IDtoModel
        where T3 : IRawDto<T1, T2>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">T3 items</param>
        /// <returns>DTO items</returns>
        public IEnumerable<T2> GetDtos(IEnumerable<T3> items)
        {
            IEnumerable<T2> result = Enumerable.Empty<T2>();

            // Something like this, not able to figure out
            //result = items
            //    .Select(x => T3.GetDto((T1)x))
            //    .ToList();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I read interfaces can't have static methods until some c# 8.
Is this an overkill for a conversion, should i implement this conversion in individual classes?

Comment: What is ```T1(x)``` means?

Comment: I don't think this is possible to use ```static``` to do that if use ```static ``` for performance maybe you could try ```Singleton```

Comment: Maybe use ```reflection``` could do it but I don't think it's what you want

Comment: I wouldn't go for typing your DTO's by hand and trying to optimize the classes by using generic. I'd rather look for a tool that's generating the DTO's

Comment: @MichaelMao corrected it to (T1)x

Comment: What do you gain by having it enforced by a contract (as opposed to just having a method)?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen i will look into your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @tymtam i might end up having just method. I went with contract so that i can bring the conversion to a generic method in base repo class. I'm not able to figure other way to do this.

Comment: BTW. With or without contract this approach makes one of the types know about the other and once could argue that this isn't "pure/correct" plus sometimes a `From` method on the target type works better.

Comment: Is there a reason for making the method static rather than an instance method `T To()`?